# plotting Numerical integral

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

```
g = 1;
n = 5;
G = 0.1;
E3 = g Sqrt[4 n - 2];
Y = 1 + Sin[2 A];
z[t_, A_] := FullSimplify[Sin[ArcCos[((1/8) (3 - Sin[2 A] - 
       Sin[2 A] (1 - 3 Sin[2 A]) + 
       Cos[2 E3 t] Exp[-2 G t E3^2] (1 + 
           Sin[2 A])^2 + 
       4 Cos[E3 t] Exp[-0.5 G t E3^2] Cos[
          2 A]^2))^0.5]]^2];
l[t_] := -(E3/4)*Y*(Sin [2 E3 t] + C E3 Cos[2 E3 t])*Exp[-2 G  t E3^2];
u[t_] := -(E3/2)*Cos[2 A]*(Sin [E3 t] + .5 G E3 Cos[E3 t])*Exp[-.5 G  t E3^2];
L3[t_, A_] := l[t] - Sqrt[l[t]^2 + u[t]^2];
d = Plot[z[s, A]/NIntegrate[Abs[L3[t, A]], {t, 0, s}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 10], {s, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

I want to plot this function for Many different values of `A=0;pi/3,pi/4` in one plot but I get more problem when I may to use Table function.

Comment: `C` is a protected symbol; use a different variable. In general, avoid starting your names with capital letters, especially single-letter variables.  Give `A` and whatever variable you use for `C` numeric values.  Then plot `z[s, A]/NDSolveValue[{y'[t] == Abs[L3[t, A]], y[0] == 0}, 
  y[s], {t, 0, 1}]`.  Evaluate it before plotting: `Plot[z[s, A]/
   NDSolveValue[{y'[t] == Abs[L3[t, A]], y[0] == 0}, 
    y[s], {t, 0, 1}] // Evaluate, {s, 0, 1}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `NIntegrate` and `Plot` to work you need to feed them with numerical values.

```
g = 1;
n = 5;
G = 0.1;
E3 = g Sqrt[4 n - 2];
Y[A_?NumericQ] := 1 + Sin[2 A];
Cc = 1;
```

It is better use `Set` instead of `SetDelayed` with `FullSimplify` to compute it once and not repeatedly:

```
z[t_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ] = 
  FullSimplify[
   Sin[ArcCos[((1/8) (3 - Sin[2 A] - Sin[2 A] (1 - 3 Sin[2 A]) + 
           Cos[2 E3 t] Exp[-2 G t E3^2] (1 + Sin[2 A])^2 + 
           4 Cos[E3 t] Exp[-0.5 G t E3^2] Cos[2 A]^2))^0.5]]^2];

l[t_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ] := -(E3/4)*
   Y[A]*(Sin[2 E3 t] + Cc E3 Cos[2 E3 t])*Exp[-2 G t E3^2];
u[t_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ] := -(E3/2)*
   Cos[2 A]*(Sin[E3 t] + .5 G E3 Cos[E3 t])*Exp[-.5 G t E3^2];
L3[t_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ] := l[t, A] - Sqrt[l[t, A]^2 + u[t, A]^2];
```

And a helper function for `Plot`:

```
pl[s_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ, t_] := 
 z[s, A]/NIntegrate[Abs[L3[t, A]], {t, 0, s}]
```

Now we can plot for several values of `A`:

```
With[{avalues = {0, π/3, π/4}}, 
 Plot[Evaluate[pl[s, #, t] & /@ avalues], {s, 0.01, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> (Row[{HoldForm@A, "\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]", #}] & /@ avalues), 
  PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Alx, the problem is solved

Comment: Glad to help you!

Comment: This problem disturbed me for one month, never forget you

Answer (score 2):

`A` is undefined and `NIntegrate` will refuse to accept this so assign some constant numeric value to `A`. `C` is a predefined symbol in Mathematica, perhaps rename that to be`Cc` and assign some constant numeric value to `Cc`. If you start `s` at zero then you get a division by zero error so start at some small positive value. With those changes then try

```
ListPlot[Table[{s,z[s,A]/NIntegrate[Abs[L3[t,A]],{t,0,s}]},{s,1/40,1,1/40}],Joined->True]
```

and you should see your desired plot

To have multiple plots for different values of `A` try this

```
Show[Table[
 ListPlot[Table[{s,z[s,A]/NIntegrate[Abs[L3[t,A]],{t,0,s}],{s,1/20,1,1/20}],Joined->True],
 {A,0,Pi,Pi/6}],PlotRange->All]
```

but for some values of `A` it complains about zero denominators and the integrals not being accurate.

Comment: Thanks bill but ListPlot function cannot give the exact approximation to my computations